# Скачать файл при успешной отправке формы php

Tags: php

Есть обработчик формы. Нужно чтобы при успешной отправке формы скачивался файл xls, который расположен на сервере. Подскажите как можно реализовать

```
<?php
$to = "test@gmail.com";

$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From:  <admin@test.com>\r\n";

$Email  = trim($_POST["email"]);
$message = "<b>Email:</b> $Email";
$subject = "Заявка";

mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: http://test.com/thanks/');
```

Comment: А что вы читали по этому вопросу, что нашли, и в чем затык кроме «я не знаю как покажите мне»? Где самостоятельно проделанная работа, которая покажет что вы действительно пытались выяснить, а не скопировали код откуда-то ещё для своих нужд, и ожидаете что вам его подгонят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

download_file('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhQIG.jpg', 'Картинка.jpg');

function download_file($file, $name) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $name);
    exit(readfile($file));
}
```

[Почитайте здесь.](https://habr.com/ru/post/151795/)